# CSS's transition's ease-in-out doesn't seem to work

Tags: html, css, markup

I have a simple overlay of text over an image, darkening the background in the process. I used `transition` with `ease-in-out`, but it doesn't seem to ease out properly.

I know that the `ease-in-out` should be applied to the thing itself, and not its pseudo of `:hover`, but it doesn't seem to want to work. I have tried many ways, moving it around, deleting stuff, adding stuff, but nothing seems to make sense.
I notice the text do ease out fine, but the `background` with `rgba` opacity doesn't co-operate. It just snaps back :(

Do refer to a live version at http://g4stly.com/staff.html to know what I'm talking about, specifically.

Thanks in advance!

My code is as follows:

```css
#g4stly
   {
   background-image: url('http://g4stly.com/images/users/g4stly.jpg');
   }

.textFrame
   {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #DDAA49;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   border-radius: 30%;
   width: 250px;
   height: 250px;
   }
   
.textFrame p
   {
   opacity: 0;
   height: 75%;
   margin: 0;
   border-radius: 30%;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
   }
   
.textFrame p a
   {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #976649;
   font-size: 25px;
   }
   
.textFrame:hover p
   {
   opacity: 1;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   }
   
.textFrame p:first-child
   {
   padding: 25% 0 0 0;
   }
```

```html
<div id="g4stly" class="textFrame textFrameLeft">
  <p><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198068338533/" target="_blank">g4stly</a><br><br>
  Owner of everything g4stly related<br>
  Basically, the boss.</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you updated the code. Looks like your issue has already been solved.

The `.textFrame p` was only applying transition for `opacity`, so you couldn't see the background transition. I seed you added `background ....` to the transition, you could also do:

`transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;`

Another option would be to move the `rgba` background to inside the `.textFrame p`, so the background wouldn't suddenly disappear, fading out along with the rest of the element.

Hopefully this helps you understand the cause :)

Comment: was just about to say this :)

Comment: Yup, I find myself contradicting my own thoughts many a times on this site, which is seriously frustrating. I was wondering what was going wrong, i tried so many things, read up on many things and nothing worked, only to realise it was a simple problem. Only when I posted this question that I actually re-read the line, and reading the word "opacity" only made me realise how dumb I was not  to realise that it was affecting only the opacity. I added a second line with another transition, which makes it all not work at all.

Comment: Then a quick google search told me to use a comma and add the next transition, as a second transition statement destroys both of them. I feel dumb D:

Comment: I know the feeling, it can happen to all of us @Mark :)

Answer (score 1):

You had a comma where there should have been a semicolon.

```
transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out;
```

```css
#g4stly {
  background-image: url('http://g4stly.com/images/users/g4stly.jpg');
}

.textFrame {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #DDAA49;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 30%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.textFrame p {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 75%;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 30%;
  transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

.textFrame p a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #976649;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.textFrame:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.textFrame p:first-child {
  padding: 25% 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="g4stly" class="textFrame textFrameLeft">
  <p><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198068338533/" target="_blank">g4stly</a><br><br> Owner of everything g4stly related<br> Basically, the boss.</p>
</div>
```